# Alter tablespace through stored procedure on db2

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, partitioning

I'm trying to write a stored proc for reclaiming disk space after partition is deleted in db2.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RECLAIM_PARTITION_SPACE(OUT RESPONSE_MESS 
VARCHAR(200))
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN   
DECLARE REDUCE_STOP VARCHAR(200);
DECLARE LOWER_HIGH_WATER_MARK VARCHAR(200);
DECLARE REDUCE_MAX VARCHAR(200);
DECLARE V_MSG VARCHAR(80);
DECLARE V_OUTSTATUS INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE V_SECONDS INTEGER DEFAULT 300;

SET REDUCE_STOP = 'ALTER TABLESPACE TS_PART_TABLES REDUCE STOP';
SET LOWER_HIGH_WATER_MARK = 'ALTER TABLESPACE TS_PART_TABLES LOWER HIGH WATER MARK';
SET REDUCE_MAX = 'ALTER TABLESPACE TS_PART_TABLES REDUCE MAX';

BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE REDUCE_STOP;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE LOWER_HIGH_WATER_MARK;
END;

CALL DBMS_ALERT.WAITONE('wait for reduce max' , V_MSG , V_OUTSTATUS , V_SECONDS);

BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE REDUCE_STOP;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE REDUCE_MAX;
END;
COMMIT WORK;        
END@

GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE RECLAIM_PARTITION_SPACE(VARCHAR(200)) TO 
USER DB2INST1@
```

But when I run this stored proc no reclaim happens, however when I manually run the query ALTER TABLESPACE TS_PART_TABLES LOWER HIGH WATER MARK followed by ALTER TABLESPACE TS_PART_TABLES REDUCE MAX the disk space is reclaimed for deleted partitions.

What am I doing wrong in the stored procedure?

Comment: Have you tried to commit after `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE LOWER_HIGH_WATER_MARK`? What's the purpose of using `CALL DBMS_ALERT.WAITONE`? Do you check, if the extent movement process has finished on this tablespace and send a signal afterwards from another session?

Comment: Are you aware that you can just use `REDUCE MAX` – there's no need to `LOWER HIGH WATERMARK` first.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein Thanks. Adding commit after EXECUTE IMMEDIATE worked. There is an implicit commit performed with DDL statements, not DML statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding Commit after EXECUTE IMMEDIATE LOWER_HIGH_WATER_MARK and EXECUTE IMMEDIATE REDUCE_MAX solved the problem. 
That is because while using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE there is an implicit commit performed with DDL statements, not DML statements. (Source: https://searchoracle.techtarget.com/answer/Telling-EXECUTE-IMMEDIATE-to-commit)